# How to get Hudson CI to execute a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, hudson, policy, execution

I'm using **Hudson version 1.324** for CI and have a couple of issues:

Environment:

- Windows Server 2008
- Powershell v1.0
- Hudson 1.324 running as a service
- Hudson Powershell Plugin installed
- Psake (aka. "Powershell Make/Rake" available from Github) 0.23
  (All current/latest versions as of this initial post)

I have a Powershell (PS) script that works to compile, run NUnit tests, and if successful, create a 7z file of the output. The PS script works from the command line, on both my local development box as well as the CI server where Hudson is installed.

**1) Execution Policy with Powershell.**

I initially ran a PS console on the server, ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`, which allows any script to be run. (Yes, I realize the security concerns here, I'm trying to get something to work and Unrestricted should remove the security issues so I can focus on other problems.)

[This worked, and allowed me to fire off the PS build script from Hudson yesterday. I then encountered another problem, but we'll discuss that more in item #2.]

Once Hudson could fire off a PS script, it complained with the following error:

> "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell "&
>   'OzSystems.Tools\psake\psake.ps1' '.\oz-build.ps1'"  The term
>   'OzSystems.Tools\psake\psake.ps1' is not recognized as a cmdlet, funct
>   ion, operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.
>   At line:1 char:2
>   + &  <<<< 'OzSystems.Tools\psake\psake.ps1' '.\oz-build.ps1'"

Using the same command line, I am able to successfully execute the PS script from the command line manually. However Hudson is unable to get PS to do the same. After looking at additional PS documentation I also tried this:

```
"& 'OzSystems.Tools\psake\psake.ps1' '.\oz-build.ps1'"
```

and got a similar error. There does not appear to be any documentation for the Powershell plugin for Hudson. I've gone through all the Powershell plugin files and don't see anything that's configurable. I can't find a log file for Hudson to get additional information.

Can anyone help me past this?

**2)** I spent yesterday wrestling with #1. I came in this AM and tried to dig in again, after restarting the Hudson server/service, and now it appears that the ExecutionPolicy has been reset to Restricted. I did what worked yesterday, opened a PS console and `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to `Unrestricted`. It shows `Unrestricted` in the PS console, but Hudson says that it doesn't have rights to execution PS scripts. I reopened a new PS console and confirmed that the `ExecutionPolicy` is still `Unrestriced` -- it is. But Hudson evidently is not aware of this change. Restarting Hudson service again does not change Hudson's view of the policy.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks, Derek

Comment: I am running into the exact same problem.  Honestly how this powershell thing is suppose to be comparable to bash is beyond me.  Too much security!

Comment: Going through the painful process that is signing the script (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx) didn't help.  FYI.

Comment: Make sure that you didn't somehow set-executionpolicy for the -Scope CurrentUser instead of -Scope LocalMachine ... and make sure that Hudson isn't trying to run your builds on another client ;)

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the problem of running powershell scripts in hudson. The thing is that you are running a 32-bit process of Java, and you've configured Hudson for 64-bit but not for 32-bit. See the following thread we created at microsoft.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/a9c08f7e-c557-46eb-b8a6-a19ba457e26d

If your lazy.
1. Start powershell (x86) from the start menu as administrator
2. Set the execution policy to remotesigned

Run this once and your homefree.

Comment: Thanks! I had a slightly different problem than the original poster, but setting the execution policy in x86 as well fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

When Running PowerShell from a scheduled task or Hudson you want to:

1. Specify the -ExecutionPolicy parameter (in your case: `-Ex Unrestricted`)
2. Specify that command using *either* `-Command { ... }` or `-File` *NOT BOTH* and not without specifying which you mean.

Try this (except that I don't recommend using relative paths):

```
PowerShell.exe -Ex Unrestricted -Command "C:\Path\To\OzSystems.Tools\psake\psake.ps1" ".\oz-build.ps1"
```

To be clear, this will work too:

```
PowerShell.exe -Ex Unrestricted -Command "&{&'OzSystems.Tools\psake\psake.ps1' '.\oz-build.ps1'}"
```

The first string after -Command is interpreted as THE NAME OF A COMMAND, and every parameter after that is just passed to that command as a parameter. The string is NOT a script, it's the name of a command (in this case, a script file)... you **cannot** put `"&'OzSystems.Tools\psake\psake.ps1'"` but you can put `"OzSystems.Tools\psake\psake.ps1"` even if it has spaces.

To quote from the help (run `PowerShell -?`) emphasis mine:

> **`-Command`**
>
> Executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they were
>       typed at the Windows PowerShell command prompt, and then exits, unless
>       NoExit is specified. The value of Command can be "-", a string. or a
>       script block.
>
> If the value of Command is "-", the command text is read from standard
>       input.
>
> If the value of Command is a script block, the script block must be enclosed
>       in braces ({}). You *can specify a script block only when running PowerShell.exe
>       in Windows PowerShell*. The results of the script block are returned
>       to the parent shell as deserialized XML objects, not live objects.
>
> If the value of Command is a string, Command must be the last parameter
>       in the command , because any characters typed after the command are
>       interpreted as the command arguments.

Answer (score 1):

For question #1, try this (assuming you are using PowerShell 2.0):

"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell -executionPolicy Unrestricted -file OzSystems.Tools\psake\psake.ps1 C:\{path}\oz-build.ps1"

You are using "." for the path to oz-build.ps1.  I suspect you will need to provide the full path to your oz-build.ps1 file to make this work.  Unless the infrastructure that executes the command above happens to have the current dir set correctly.  And even if it is set correctly for the "process", that only matters to .NET/Win32 API calls and not to PowerShell cmdlets.  Current dir in PowerShell is tracked differently than the process's current dir because PowerShell can have multiple runspaces running simultaneously.  That sort of global, mutable value doesn't work in this concurrent scenario.

As for question #2, what account does the Hudson service run under?  Make sure that account has executed Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned (or unrestricted).

Comment: Keith,

I've tried the suggestions for #1. Same problems.

For #2, Yes, I have made sure the ExecutionPolicy is set for the account that Hudson is running under. It is Unrestricted when I log in manually to check the ExecutionPolicy. Hudson's still saying that scripts are disabled.

We're about to punt on Powershell and try Rake with Hudson. It appears PS is not quite ready for prime time, or at least not behaving consistently enough for us to rely on.

Thanks for the input Keith!

Comment: Before giving up, try using the -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted parameter. I've modified the example above to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problems as you (as you've seen from my comments).  I have given up on the powershell launcher and moved to running things using the batch file launcher.  Even though I had set the system to unrestricted that setting didn't seem to matter to hudson's launcher.  I don't know if it runs in some other context or something, even adding things to the global profile.ps1 didn't seem to help.  What I ended up doing was running

```
powershell " set-executionpolicy Unrestricted; & 'somefile.ps1'"
```

which does what I need, although it isn't ideal.  I've e-mailed the plugin author about this and will update.

Answer (score 1):

I just got through this exact problem. What a pain!

If you are running a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit Windows, make sure that you set the execution policy for the 32-bit Powershell interface.  I found my 32 bit executable here:

```
C:\Windows\syswow64\Windowspowershell\v1.0\powerhsell.exe
```

The 32- and 64-bit Powershell environments are completely distinct so setting the execution policy in one has no effect on the other.